# Выбрать элемент href в javascript'е

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как выбрать элемент и при нажатии вывести `alert('ok');`

Нужно выбрать этот элемент href

```
<a role="button" ng-if="App.settings.game !== 'minecraft'" href="/files/stores/backend/steam.php?login">Войти</a>
```

мой код

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/files/stores/backend/steam.php?login']");

btn.onclick = function(){
    alert('ok');
};
```

Но это не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Если на странице будет один такой элемент, `querySelector` без `All`, находит первый элемент и усё:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('a[href="#bubu"]');

btn.onclick = function(){
  console.log('ok');
};
```

```html
<a href="#bubu">Войти</a>
```

А `querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию элементов. Даже если этот элемент один. А у коллекции нет свойства `onclick` - есть у его элементов.

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#bubu"]');

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log('Кликнута кнопка номер ' + i);
  }
};
```

```html
<a href="#bubu">Войти</a>
<a href="#bubu">Войти</a>
<a href="#bubu">Войти</a>
<a href="#bubu">Войти</a>
<a href="#bubu">Войти</a>
```

Даже если уверены, что такая ссылка только одна, ничего не будет, если перестраховаться и написать All.